# Angular Adal how to retrieve the username or email

Tags: angularjs, adal.js

I have written an angular js app that I am using angular-adal.js to authenticate against Azure AD. I have configured all routes to requireADLogin and also added

```
extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1,scope=openid'
```

in the init method.

My question is where can I pull the logged in username or email etc from to store against the records they are creating after they've logged in. Because I am not manually authenticating in code I don't have a token object or anything to play with. Any pointers would be appreciated as although I've searched all the exmaples seem to be when you are making the calls yourself rather than letting UI Router do the authentication.

I'm sure this must be a common thing to do though!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solved the issue ?

Comment: if dalAuthenticationService.userInfo is not giving both username & email, try to use Graph API. But, you need to add Graph API in azure-ad who has access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After we sign-in the Angular application using ADAl library, it provides `userInfo` object which we can get the information about the user. And we can get the `userName` from this object directly.

Here is the code and figure for your reference:

```
$scope.printUserName = function () {
                    console.log(adalAuthenticationService.userInfo.userName);
                };
```

[image]

The Microsoft also provide a code sample for the Angular application, you can refer it from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp.git).

Comment: Many thanks!! I was looking in that sample project you linked to but couldn't find an example of getting the username when not making the call directly! This is very useful!

Comment: Do you also know a way to do it in Angular 2 with adal-ts?

Comment: I want to get email field. Any idea ?

Comment: @Anas, check this.adalService.userInfo.userName field this.adalService.userInfo.profile.email field. It will be somewhere. If not properly open total console.log(this.adalService.userInfo) and check inside profile.... The total response. If not, we can do Graph API to retrieve. Let me know what happens?But, you need to add Graph API in azure-ad who has access